# How to set the cell data type in POI?

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi

Now I am successfully setting the number cell type using POI. For example, `#,##0.00` formats as `1,343.23`.

However, when I want to make `#,##0.#####`, I get `1343.23000`, here the thousand separator `","` disappeared. How can I show like this `1,343.23000`?

```
doubleStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
doubleStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("#,##0.#####"));
```

Comment: Does this help you? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439591/number-and-cell-formatting-in-apache-poi

Comment: Your format `#,##0.#####` simply is not a built in format. See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats for how to create data formats.

Answer (score 1):

```
doubleStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
doubleStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0.#######"));
```

I had to set my format.