# How to set Cell Format using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, spreadsheet

can i set the format in cell using apache poi?
i was trying with this code :

```
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("test");

HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell c = row.createCell(0);
c.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
c.setCellValue(111);
```

and I was trying with this code from this link :
[Number and cell Formatting in apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439591/number-and-cell-formatting-in-apache-poi)

but it does not work. it is still in GENERAL Format. I want it change to NUMBER

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjbCm.png)

Comment: Cell type is independent of cell format.

Comment: so it is impossible to set it automatically using POI or anything? @JimGarrison

Comment: What you have marked in the screen shot is the **format**, not the type. The default Number format would be the built in format 2: `style.setDataFormat((short)0x2);` or 1: `style.setDataFormat((short)0x1);`.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter , it is so help me